# Mismatch delete

Tags: c++, dynamic, valgrind, mismatch

I have program which implements database of peoples and his companies. I have created dynamic array of pointer to class members instead of dynamic array of class members, cause copying is quicker with it.

I have version which works but valgrind shows mismatch delete in destructor (delete db)

```
CCompany** db;

~CCompanyIndex ( void )
{
    for(unsigned i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        /*cout<<"dealloc:"<<db[i]<<endl;*/
        delete db[i];
    }
    delete db;
}

CCompanyIndex ( void )
{
    max=1000;
    len=0;
    db=new CCompany*[max];
}
```

I use also to add

```
CCompany* newIt=new CCompany(oName,oAddr,cName,cAddr);
```

So I have tried following code which I consider correct previously

```
~CCompanyIndex ( void )
{
    delete [] db;
}
```

But then all memory allocated by adding method is not deallocated.

Comment: (1) Are you familiar with the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)?  (2) Have you considered smart pointers and containers instead of raw pointers and dynamically-allocated memory?

Answer (score 21):

The first sample is almost correct. You're deleting each element in a `for` loop, but then you attempt to `delete` the array.

```
for(unsigned i=0;i<len;i++) { delete db[i]; }
delete db;
```

It should instead be:

```
for(unsigned i=0;i<len;i++) { delete db[i]; }
delete[] db;
```

Whenever you use `new ...[]`, you should be using `delete[]`.

Also, don't forget the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) (or [Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11) (or [Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/))).

Answer (score 9):

You are using the wrong `delete`.  Do this:

```
CCompanyIndex::~CCompanyIndex()
{
    for(unsigned i=0; i<len;i++) delete db[i];
    delete [] db;
}
```

Note the `delete []` call.

Answer (score 2):

You need `delete db[i]` for each element but `delete[] db` for the array itself, so neither destructor was correct.

Arrays allocated with `new Foo[n]` must be deallocated with the array form, `delete[]`, that's what `valgrind` means about mismatch new/delete

Comment: Better still, don't use `new[]` or `delete[]`. Use a vector and be happy.